# Can't get List() function to working with array

Tags: php

Here is my simple code and i'm not able to understand why and how...

```
$len = 5;   // total number of numbers
$min = 1;  // minimum
$max = 90;  // maximum
$range = array(); // initialize array
foreach (range(0, $len - 1) as $i) {
    while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));
    //$range[] = $num;
    list($br1, $br2, $br3, $br4, $br5) = $range;
}
print_r($range);

//echo $br1." ".$br2." ".$br3." ".$br4." ".$br5;
```

Hope in your help...! Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you resetting values inside of an array?

Comment: this script is for getting unique random numbers in a range from 1 to 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be written as:

```
<?php
$len = 5;   // total number of numbers
$min = 1;   // minimum
$max = 90;  // maximum
$range = array(); // initialize array
foreach (range(0, $len - 1) as $i) { // you need to repeat the loop $len times
    // get a new random number in the given range and assign it to $num,
    // do it until the generated number is unique (not present in $range)
    // the loop body is empty, as all the action happens inside its condition
    while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));

    // append the random number to array
    $range[] = $num;
}
list($br1, $br2, $br3, $br4, $br5) = $range;
echo $br1." ".$br2." ".$br3." ".$br4." ".$br5;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/869094).

The existing version of your code never updates `$range` variable (the corresponding line is commented out for some reason), that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, now its perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need simple modification in your code.Your are assign list in side loop.But which is put out site of loop. And your variable range array are need commented

```
$len = 5;   // total number of numbers
$min = 1;  // minimum
$max = 90;  // maximum
$range = array(); // initialize array
foreach (range(0, $len - 1) as $i) {
      while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));
       $range[] = $num;
    }
  list($br1, $br2, $br3, $br4, $br5) = $range;
  print_r($br1);
  print_r($br2);

 //echo $br1." ".$br2." ".$br3." ".$br4." ".$br5;
```